# Using std::invoke when a function is overloaded

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, std-invoke

I am trying to use `std::invoke()` with an overloaded function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct S {
    void foo(int) { }
    void foo(int, int) { }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::invoke(&S::foo, s, 1);
}
```

but I get an error: `'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found`. It works fine, when there is the only one function with name `foo()`. Is it possible to use `std::invoke()` when a function is overloaded?

Comment: You can help compiler to choose the proper overload by casting: `static_cast<void (S::*)(int)>(&S::foo)`

Comment: You can also eliminate the problem by wrapping the call in a lambda. `std::invoke([&]() { s.foo(1); })`.

Comment: @super thanks, your solution also works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two example solutions:

```cpp
std::invoke(static_cast<void(S::*)(int)>(&S::foo), s, 1);
std::invoke([&s]() { s.foo(1); });
```

Comment: why do you cast `1` to an `int` ?